# Salesforce1 possible bug related lists?

Tags: salesforce1-app, activities

I noticed something strange with the "Open Activities" related list in Salesforce1.
In Salesforce1, it's not showing the open activities while in the regular Salesforce, the activities are showing correctly in the related list.

If I go in the "Tasks" menu item of Salesforce1, I DO see the task and it says Related to account XYZ. If I navigate from the task to the related account and then go to the related lists, also via this path it's not showing the open activities.

Did anyone else notice this issue?

Salesforce1:
[image]

[image]

Regular Salesforce:
[image]

Comment: Interesting...could be a bug. Complete conjecture here but the MRU list functionality of S1 might be coming into play here. What happens if you click on the activity in the desktop browser and go back to S1? I wouldn't have thought you would want that behavior...and other related lists don't do that, but...

Comment: Browsing to the task in the desktop and then refreshing in S1 doesn't seem to make a difference. I would find it very strange that the MRU list functionality would also affect related lists indeed.

Comment: I DO have recordtypes on the task object. I'm not sure if that could break things. (it shouldn't anyway)

Comment: I did just read this in the Salesforce1 app getting started guide but I wonder what they mean by it...
'When you view a record in Salesforce1, you see the fields, Visualforce 
pages, and related lists that are based on the record type and the 
user’s profile in the full Salesforce desktop UI. Related lists show up 
as single-line cards containing the name of the page or related list.'

Comment: That shouldn't have anything to do with anything as it relates to what you report. Honestly, I would suggest ensuring you have the latest update to S1 installed on your mobile device, and if so, then raising a case for this ASAP.

Comment: We indeed have the latest S1 version and we also have the problem on the browser version of S1 so indeed I think it must be a bug. (case already submitted, awaiting feedback)

Comment: Shot in the dark, really. I vote for bug.

Comment: Just curious - did the case get feedback? Is this a known issue in Salesforce1 ? Trying to decide whether we create a visualforce component to work around this for the time being.

Comment: @AdamMichaelDaw the case is still open with Salesforce support and I'm awaiting feedback from backline support on this one. It's 99% a bug I would say but unclear what is triggering the bug.

Comment: Thanks @KoenVM . We're seeing this as well, with Events specifically.

Comment: I am encountering exactly this issue with Salesforce1. Were you able to figure out why the activities were showing on the browser but not on Salesforce1?

Comment: Also, the New Event , New Task related list buttons are not showing up in Salesforce1 - Any solution on that as well?